# Delegate type Cannot convert anonymous method

Tags: c#, winforms

getting error in following line "this.dgvReport.Invoke(delegate"

> *"Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type"*

```
    public void FillProductGrid()
    {
        ProductSP productSP = new ProductSP();
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        string productname = "";
        dtbl = productSP.StockReport(productname, this.cbxPrint.Checked);
        this.dgvReport.Invoke(delegate
        {
            this.dgvReport.DataSource = dtbl;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add casting to some delegate type with same signature:

```
this.dgvReport.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate {
        this.dgvReport.DataSource = dtbl;
}));
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Invoke` method has a parameter of type `Delegate`, and you can only convert an anonymous function to a *specific* delegate type. You either need to cast the expression, or (my preferred option) use a separate local variable:

```
// Or MethodInvoker, or whatever delegate you want.
Action action = delegate { this.dgvReport.DataSource = dtbl; };
dgvReport.Invoke(action);
```

Alternatively, you can create an extension method on `Control` to special-case a particular delegate, which can make it simpler:

```
public static void InvokeAction(this Control control, Action action)
{
    control.Invoke(action);
}
```

Then:

```
dgvReport.InvokeAction(delegate { dgvReport.DataSource = dtbl; });
```

Also consider using a lambda expression:

```
dgvReport.InvokeAction(() => dgvReport.DataSource = dtbl);
```